# Configurar base de datos en produccion

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hola estoy utilizando php y termine la aplicacion, pero no se como configurar la conexion ya que en local lo tenia asi

```
$server = "localhost";
$userdb = "elusuario";
$passdb = "lacontraseña";   
$nombredb = "nombreBD";
```

Pero ahora en produccion estoy utilizando phpmyadmin.. mi pregunta aca es en server doy la url de mi host hasta phpmyadmin? ya que creo que no me conecta la base de datos

Comment: Las credenciales de acceso te las debe de proveer tu servicio de hosting, ya revisaste en tu cPanel?

Comment: Si, estoy poniendo las contraseñas que me dieron, pero tambien le dejo el local host como $server ?

Comment: o le pongo literal : https://eldominio.com:2083/cpsess0884917603/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin/index.php

Comment: No, dentro de los mismos datos te deben indicar el valor que va, pues localhost solo es para desarrollo en tu propia pc

Comment: Esa era mi duda, entonces tengo que buscar el dato y quitar localhost, con razon no me conectaba, gracias